# Ring-theoretic characterization of open affines?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, ag.algebraic-geometry, schemes

#### Background

Recall that, given two commutative rings $A$ and $B$, the set of morphisms of rings $A\to B$ is in bijection with the set of morphisms of schemes $\mathrm{Spec}(B)\to\mathrm{Spec}(A)$.  Furthermore, we know that Spec$(A)$ has a base of open affine subsets, the "basic" or "principal" open affines $D(f)$ for all $f\in A$. Furthermore, $D(f)\cong \mathrm{Spec}(A_f)$ as schemes, and the inclusion $D(f)\hookrightarrow\mathrm{Spec}(A)$ corresponds to the localization map $A\to A_f$.

But answers to a [recent MathOverflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/7153/open-affine-subscheme-of-affine-scheme-which-is-not-principal) show that open affine subschemes of affine schemes can arise in other ways.

---

#### Question

In order to try to make sense of the situation above, I'd like to know the following.

> Given a commutative ring $A$, is there a "ring-theoretic" characterization of the ring homomorphisms $A\to B$ that realize $\mathrm{Spec}(B)$ as an open affine subscheme of $\mathrm{Spec}(A)$ (more precisely, those morphisms such that the induced map $\mathrm{Spec}(B)\to\mathrm{Spec}(A)$ is an open immersion)?

Of course, "ring-theoretic" is a bit vague. Let's certainly avoid any tautological characterizations.  I would prefer if an answer didn't make any reference to the Zariski topology (for instance, the morphisms $A\to A_f$ make perfect sense without the Zariski topology), but I'm not sure whether that's reasonable.

---

**Update:** I received two great answers, thank you both!  I chose the one that was closer to the kind of condition that I had in mind.  But Dan Petersen's answer was also very interesting and unexpected.

Comment: Isn't $D(f)\cong Spec(A_f)$ as schemes ? But not to $Spec(A)$.

Comment: @Susobhan Certainly, thank you!  I have fixed the issue.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

**Theorem 1**: Let $R$ be an integral domain with field of fractions $K$, and $R \to A$ a homomorphism. Then $Spec(A) \to Spec(R)$ is an open immersion if and only if $A=0$ or $R \to K$ factors through $R \to A$ (i.e. $A$ is birational over $R$) and $A$ is flat and of finite type over $R$.

Proof: Assume $Spec(A) \to Spec(R)$ is an open immersion and $A \neq 0$. It is known that open immersions are flat and of finite type. Thus the same is true vor $R \to A$. Now $R \to K$ is injective, thus also $A \to A \otimes_R K$. In particular, $A \otimes_R K \neq 0$. Open immersions are stable under base change, so that $Spec(A \otimes_R K) \to Spec(K)$ is an open immersion. But since $Spec(K)$ has only one element and $Spec(A \otimes_R K)$ is non-empty, it has to be an isomorphism, i.e. $K \to A \otimes_R K$ is an isomorphism. Now $R \to A \to A \otimes_R K \cong K$ is the desired factorization.

Of course, the converse is not as trivial. It is proven in the paper

> Susumu Oda, On finitely generated birational flat extensions of integral domains
>   Annales mathématiques Blaise Pascal, 11 no. 1 (2004), p. 35-40

It is available [online](http://ambp.cedram.org/item?id=AMBP_2004__11_1_35_0). In the section "Added in Proof." you can find some theorems concerning the general case without integral domains. In particular, it is remarked that in E.G.A. it is shown that

**Theorem 2**: $Spec(A) \to Spec(R)$ is an open immersion if and only if $R \to A$ is flat, of finite presentation and an epimorphism in the category of rings.

More generally, in EGA IV, 17.9.1 it is proven that a morphism of schemes is an open immersion if and only if it is flat, a (categorical) monomorphism and locally of finite presentation.

There are several descriptions of epimorphisms of rings (they don't have to be surjective), see [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/109/what-do-epimorphisms-of-commutative-rings-look-like) MO-question.

Comment: Thanks for the interesting answer, reference and reminder.

Comment: Very nice information, thank you.  Do you know what volume of EGA would have the result you refer to?

Comment: again only one direction is hard. in EGA IV 2.4.6 it is shown that $Spec(A) \to Spec(R)$ is open (but to be honest, as always, I can track back the 'proof root' forever, without understanding anything ...). the fibre morphisms come from epis on fields, which are isomorphisms, thus the map is injective. I don't know how to prove that the stalk morphisms are bijective. 

Comment: A morphism of affines is a Zariski-open immersion if it is an étale monomorphism of affines.  Then back in our category of rings, it is an étale epimorphism because the tensor product is right-exact, so epis are stable under base change.  You can find this in stacks-GIT. 

Comment: 'owk' gave me the EGA reference. now it's in the answer.

Comment: is $Spec(A)$ defined for $A$ null ring? I thought that we only define spectra of commutative unital rings (so empty scheme is not affine).

Comment: The zero ring is, of course, a commutative unital ring. Its spectrum is the empty space. If you see a text which demands $1 \neq 0$ for a ring unit (there are many ...), throw it away, please.

Answer (score 49):

There is the following characterisation. I don't think it's too tautological. Let $T \subseteq A$ be the set of *f* such that the induced map $A[f^{-1}] \to B[f^{-1}]$ is an isomorphism. Then $\mathrm{Spec}(B) \to \mathrm{Spec}(A)$ is an open immersion if and only if the image of $T$ in $B$ generates the unit ideal.

Comment: I've never seen this cirterion before, but it's easy to prove and I like it. Even more, it inspired me to think about a kind of open-immersion-obstruction which I will present on MO as soon as I worked out some examples. Thank you! 

Comment: Thanks! I agree, it's neat. I learned it in a basic AG course taught by Torsten Ekedahl.

Comment: That's a nice characterization, thanks!  Would it be possible to give a sentence indicating how one might prove this?

Comment: If $Spec(B) \to Spec(A)$ is an open immersion, the image is a ppen subset of $Spec(A)$, thus a union of some $D(f_i)$. Then $f_i \in T$ and the preimages of the $D(f_i)$ in $Spec(B)$ cover $Spec(B)$, i.e. the images of the $f_i$ in $B$ generate the unit ideal. For the converse, assume that the image of $T$ in $B$ generates the unit ideal. For every $f \in T$, we have an isomorphism $D_B(f) \cong D_A(f)$. Remark that $T$ is closed under multiplication and that these isomorphisms are compatible, thus glue to $Spec(B) \cong \cup_{f \in T} D_A(f)$.

Comment: This is really great! 


Comment: It's worth pointing out that $T$ is in any case an ideal in $A$: indeed, if $N$ and $Q$ are the kernel and cokernel of $A\to B$ (seen as $A$-modules), then by flatness of $A[f^{-1}]$, $T$ is the set of $f$ such that the $A[f^{-1}]$-modules $N[f^{-1}]$ and $Q[f^{-1}]$ are zero; but for any $A$-module $M$ (not necessarily of finite type) the set of $f$ such that $M[f^{-1}]=0$ is the intersection of the radicals of the annihilators of all elements of $M$, so it is an ideal.

Comment: This characterization is found in Mireille Martin-Deschamps, Sur une caractérisation des ouverts affines d’un schéma affine, Comptes-Rendus Acad. Sci. Paris, t. 273, Série A, 1971, p. 38.